# Levantar ambiente de produccion o desarrollo con docker segun el comando

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

Tengo un proyecto ya configurado y funcionando con docker, en el tengo 3 servicios

```
 version: "3.1"

services:
  gui:
    image: node:11-alpine
    working_dir: /app
    command: "npm run start:beta"
    volumes:
      - ./gui:/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - api

  api:
    image: api
    build: ./api
    working_dir: /var/www/
    volumes:
      - ./api:/var/www/
      - ./api/public/:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - 8200:80
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:12
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - ./data/pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

para levantar el proyecto ejecuto **docker-compose up -d**
pero levanta el proyecto de react con el .env de beta(pues asi lo puse en docker-compose.yml)
la pregunta; ¿Hay forma de ejecutar por ejemplo **docker-compose up -d prod** y suba el .env de produccion  o **docker-compose up -d dev** y suba el .env de desarrollo?
ya tengo configurados los .env solo es subir bien el **npm run start:_*miambiente*** en el docker

Comment: Si tiene el proyecto en github puedes tener diferentes archivo .env según la rama que tengas, asi puedes levantarlo con la variables de ambientes de dicha rama.
Deben agregar al archivo .gitignore el archivo .env para que no se traspase entre las distintas ramas.

Comment: muchas gracias por responder, los diferentes .env ya estan creados , no hay problema con eso, el problema es como ejecutar el npm run start:_mi_ambiente desde docker de manera dinamica

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/326812)

Answer (score 0):

sí es posible, la recomendación para trabajar diferentes ambientes con Docker es utilizar [múltiples archivos de configuración](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files).

En el caso que planteas, podrías crear un nuevo archivo de configuración para un *ambiente_x* llamado `docker-compose.ambiente_x.yml` en donde modifiques el *command*

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  gui:
    command: "npm run start:ambiente_x"
```

Y podrías usarlo llamando a tu configuración original `docker-compose.yml` más la configuración con el nuevo comando `docker-compose.ambiente_x.yml`:

```sh
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.ambiente_x.yml up -d
```

Docker compose lo que hará será sobreescribir las opciones de tu `docker-compose.yml` original con las que declares en `docker-compose.ambiente_x.yml` de acuerdo a las [reglas de sobreescritura en su documentación](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#adding-and-overriding-configuration).

Comment: cree un yml para los ambientes por separado y ejecte tu comando docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.beta.yml up -d pero me sale este error:Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.

Comment: Hola,  ese es un problema diferente, suena a que tu docker no está corriendo. Dependiendo de tu sistema operativo en instalación deberías revisar cómo arrancarlo. Por ejemplo, en Ubuntu es con `sudo service docker start`